# PushKit with VOIP working unstable

Tags: ios, voip, linphone, pushkit

I am using Linphone lib on iOS (and Flexisip on server) to build VoIP app on iOS.

Everything working well. Only when mobile app in background mode and have incoming call, my app SOMETIME not working (not wakeup and receive incoming call).

When incoming call, Flexisip server will request to APNS to push notification to destination mobile app. My mobile app will use PushKit to receive and process this notification (as show incoming call screen)

However, sometimes it doesn't working.

Comment: Is you app getting pushkit notification in terminated state as well?

Comment: Some situation here: right after sending the app to background the app receives pushes (I can see that from logs) but after a while it just stops receiving anything. I'm starting to wonder this is  Flexisip's or Apple's fault, not delivering each and every notification.
Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling the CallKit in the same runloop? I mean AFAIK it cannot be dispatched asynchronously, you have to report the call immediately.